# Why Oracle has a table showing different data with the same database?

Tags: database, oracle

I'm having trouble with Oracle. I have one database or schema and two applications to manage some data: admin app, and client app.
I access the data through client application, it shows the rows and fields.

I access the data through admin application and can see the exact same data.

Then I make an `insert` from the admin app and I can see the new row.
Now, I access with the client and it shows the old data, I mean the database without the new row.
Even if I 'update' a field in the admin, I won't see that 'update' with the client app.

This is the insert:

```
INSERT
INTO sae_scenario_type
  (
    id,
    name,
    description,
    locked
  )
  VALUES
  (
    SEQ_SAE_SCENARIO_TYPE.nextVAL,
    'Direct_SQL_Insertion_1',
    'Direct SQL Insertion from RfoAdmin 1',
    'N'
  )
```

I've read the docs but I can't find something where one can have two versions of the same table or something like that.
I'm used to PostgreSQL and MySQL, but not Oracle. Now I have to insert rows directly into the database bypassing the client application and I can with the admin app, but I can't see them in the client app.

I'm pretty sure this is related to the Oracle configuration or something like that, but just now I don't have access to that. I'm just trying to prepare myself for a project we'll begin in a few weeks. Then I will have access to people managing the database (I hope so).

Any ideas?

Comment: did you make COMMMIT  after your insert?

Comment: Thanx! Yes you were right. I was just a commit away from being insane.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the edition Lalit Kumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I access with the client and it shows the old data, I mean the database without the new row. Even if I 'update' a field in the admin, I won't see that 'update' with the client app.

The only thing that could cause this is if you don't **COMMIT**.

You must commit after **DML** changes to make sure the changes are permanent.

```
INSERT
INTO sae_scenario_type
  (
    id,
    name,
    description,
    locked
  )
  VALUES
  (
    SEQ_SAE_SCENARIO_TYPE.nextVAL,
    'Direct_SQL_Insertion_1',
    'Direct SQL Insertion from RfoAdmin 1',
    'N'
  );

COMMIT;  --> you are missing this
```

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm),

> COMMIT
>
> Purpose
>
> Use the COMMIT statement to end your current transaction and make
>   permanent all changes performed in the transaction. A transaction is a
>   sequence of SQL statements that Oracle Database treats as a single
>   unit. This statement also erases all savepoints in the transaction and
>   releases transaction locks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you just need a commit; also you can check option on auto commit;